# Storing all values after assigning to variable

Tags: php

I have a function here that gives me all users from Moodle.

```
function getallUsers(){
global $DB;
$users= $DB->get_records('user');
foreach($users as $user){
$allusers= $user->username."<br/>";
return $allusers;
}

}
```

And another who extracts values from an url.

```
function processXML($xmlContent){
$xmlObj= new SimpleXMLElement($xmlContent);
foreach($xmlObj->unidade_curricular->inscritos->aluno as $aluno){
$result= $aluno->identificador."<br/>";
return $result;
}
}
```

I need to call these functions throughout my script and assign them to variables. I echo them, for testing, but I'm only getting the first value. How can i store all values?

```
$allUsers=  array();
$allUsers= getallUsers();
echo $allUsers; 
$dataClip=  array();
$dataClip= processXML($content_b);
echo $dataClip;
```

Comment: You are only storing the results in a scalar. You need to use an array or a hash.

Comment: If you use `print_r($allUsers)`, you will see pretty quickly where the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you call `return` in `foreach` loop. Also you are assinging user into `$allusers` instead of adding user to the array.

Try with:

```
function getallUsers(){
  global $DB;
  $allusers = array();
  $users = $DB->get_records('user');

  foreach($users as $user){
    $allusers[]= $user->username;
  }

  return $allusers;
}

function processXML($xmlContent){
  $xmlObj = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlContent);

  $result = array();
  foreach ($xmlObj->unidade_curricular->inscritos->aluno as $aluno){
    $result[] = $aluno->identificador."<br/>";
  }

  return $result;
}
```

Printing users do with:

```
$allUsers = getallUsers();

echo implode('<br/>', $allUsers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix your first function, you keep reassigning the variable

```
function getallUsers(){
    global $DB;
    $users= $DB->get_records('user');
    $allusers = "";
    foreach($users as $user)
        $allusers .= $user->username."<br/>";

    return $allusers;
}
```

Also, you were returning from within the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are only storing the results in a scalar. You need to use an array or a hash. For example you could do:

push @result, $aluno->identificador;

and then you could return that array

Answer (score 0):

There are actually two things here that went 'wrong' :)

First item is the `return` part. A function only returns 1 value. All returns after that don't get excecuted:

```
function example($test){
    if($test == 'foo'){ return 'bar'; }
   return 'no bar';
}
```

If `$test=='foo'` it will return 'bar'. Because it has returned a value, 'no bar' will not be returned. This is why you only get the first value.

The other problem is that you only save one value:

```
for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++ ){
    $value = $i;
}
echo $value;
```

This will result in `10`. Only the last value is saved, it overwrites `$value` the other 9 times.

To fix this, arrays:

```
for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++ ){
    $value[] = $i;
}
```

You can not echo arrays, but you can see them like this:

```
print_r ($value); // this will give the values.
echo implode(" / ", $value); // concat them to a string -> 0 / 1 / 2 / etc
```